# How do I make writeFileSync not overwrite previous data

Tags: node.js, json

This line of code overwrites all previous data.
Is there are way, or another function that allows me to add the data on a new line?

```
fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'quotes.json'), JSON.stringify(quotey));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fs.appendFileSync()` will append your new content to the file.  Documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsappendfilesyncpath-data-options).

To make it a line boundary, just make sure you also add the appropriate `\n` to the data you are appending so it will be separated from the next one that is appended (this assumes previous content also ends in a `\n`.

```
fs.appendFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'quotes.json'), JSON.stringify(quotey) + "\n");
```

Comment: thank yuou works perfectly now